# MySQL Query Browser Multiple Statements

Tags: mysql, database

So, I'm using MySQL Query Browser to connect to a remote mysql server and trying to execute multiple statements. But it appears to only execute one statement at a time. For instance, it looks like the query browser is only executing a highlighted line and none of the other statements. Is there any way to execute *all* the statements in a tab?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default Resultset tabs only execute the statement the cursor is on.

To execute multiple statements at a time you need to use a Script tab. Select New Script Tab from the File menu. Note that you won't see the results of any queries in the Script tab.

Comment: Thanks! But how I can view the results of the statement execution?

Answer (score 0):

In your system save all the queries in .sql file.In MySQL Query Browser go to  Tools > MySQL Command Line Client.
In the command line connect to your database using the below command:
use [your db name].
example:use test (test is DB name)
Once connected to your db execute the following command:
source [your .sql file path]
example: source C:\Users\100390\Desktop\select.sql (select.sql is my saved .sql file)

Comment: These doesn't form qualified answer